# Adding an email to LaTeX file

Tags: titles

Is it possible to add an email just below the authors in this code?

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\title{Hello}
\author{User1 \and User2}



\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
A1
\section{Literature Review}
A2

\section{Conclusion}
A2

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 87):

Just use `\\` to drop down onto the next line.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Hello}
\author{User1 \\ email \href{mailto:me@somewhere.com}{me@somewhere.com} 
   \and User2 \\ email \href{mailto:someone@somewhere.com}{someone@somewhere.com} }

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
A1
\section{Literature Review}
A2
\section{Conclusion}
A2
\end{document}
```

[image: email]

You may want to adjust the options for the [hyperref package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) to improve the appearance.

Comment: @user3741635 --- the `article` document class has a `twocolumn` option. Note that you will need some text to see the effect of this; the body of your example will fit into the first column.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it can be included in the \author{} tag. Like so:

```
\author{User1 \\ user1@mailserver.xx \and User2 \\ user2@mailserver.xx}
```

However, note that this is not the canonical way to do it. Usually the second line in the author tag is for the author's address and affiliation which may include the email address. Sometimes, the email address is rather put into a footnote (e.g. with the \thanks{} tag inside the \author{} tag). But it can be (and is occasionally) done like this, only putting the email address without affiliation under the authors names. You might want to have the email address in monospace font which can be done by also applying the \texttt{} tag like so.

```
\author{User1 \\ \texttt{user1@mailserver.xx} \and User2 \\ \texttt{user2@mailserver.xx}}
```

Answer (score 7):

Intead of `\documentclass{article}`, perhaps you could prefer `\documentclass{amsart}`.
With the class amsart you are able to include several nice commands for author information, such as emails, which will be properly ordered in the document.
You can write the following commands:

```
   \author{User Guy}  
   \email{userguy@gmail.com}  

   \author{Another Guy}
   \email{anotherguy@yahoo.com}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Email doesn't show up.

Comment: Look at the end of the article. Is it there?

Comment: can `\email{}` also create circle around the email?